Getting the following error while trying to debug go tests in VSCode on mac
Failed to launch: could not launch process: error reading debug_info: decoding dwarf section info at offset 0xac6f38: DW_FORM_strx with no .debug_str_offsets section
I'm using:
dlv - 1.23.0
Go - 1.22.7 darwin/arm64
Facing this issue only after upgrading MacOS to Sequoia
How do I resolve this?
Have tried setting: -gcflags="all=-N -l" and have also tried clean installs for go and dlv. none of these have worked so far.

This? (I would say, searching the bug trackers should be the first thing to do when having issues like yours, not asking on SO.)

I’m voting to close this question because the Devle upstream has a bug filed for this exact problem.

@kostix why should this question get closed, having a bug filed in Delve would not have helped me at all

@Beginner, I think its the artefact of your mindset not aligned with the SO's intended purpose. SO has been created as a Q&A database of narrowly-scoped frequently occuring programming problems and solutions to them. Over time, many people have started to consider it to be "an interactive google": that is, if you can't google something (and often not even making an attempt), you just ask on SO. That's not what SO exists for, really. And no, SO is not a front-end for issue trackers of the software packages you happen to use ;-)

Hey @Harith this worked for me
go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@master


you can also update the goTools in vs code.
Click cmd+shift+p and search for  Go: Install/Update tools
enter image description here

Super helpful! After a MacOS update + VSCode update, I still had to run this to get back to a successful debug run. Thanks!

I was facing the same issue recently after updating to latest macos. What worked for me was to re-install Xcode command line tools:
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
xcode-select --install

After this, I was able to debug using dlv.

Here is the thing that helped me:
go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@master

sudo cp /Users/xxx/go/bin/dlv /Users/xxx/Applications/GoLand.app/Contents/plugins/go-plugin/lib/dlv/macarm/dlv

Found here:
https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/issues/1269#issuecomment-2364974176
